# Reliable testing of identities (example: modular functions)

Tags: simplifying-expressions, special-functions, experimental-mathematics

Take, for illustration, the following function (bonus points for anyone who identifies where it comes from!), defined on the upper half plane:

```
$Assumptions = Im[τ]>0
z[τ_] = Sum[Abs[EllipticTheta[a, 0, E^(I π τ)]],{a, 2, 4}]/
     (2 Abs[DedekindEta[τ]]) // FullSimplify
```

Now, it happens that this function is modular invariant, which means that $z(\tau+1)=z(-1/\tau)=z(\tau)$. Now it's unsurprising that *Mathematica* doesn't recognise these identities using `FullSimplify`. But one might hope that there is another way to check and search for these and similar identities.

An obvious approach is to use `PossibleZeroQ`, for example:

```
 PossibleZeroQ[z[-1/τ] - z[τ], Assumptions -> Im[τ] > 0]
```

But this evaluates to `False`! Let's just check that we're not doing something silly by choosing some random point and checking the identity to high accuracy:

```
N[z[-1/τ] - z[τ] /. τ -> Sqrt[π] + 3/17 I, {Infinity, 1000}]
```

evaluates to zero to the given accuracy. That's convincing evidence to me!

So: what's going wrong with `PossibleZeroQ`? And how to write a decent identity checking function?

Answer (score 2):

An observation rather than an answer: interestingly,

```
ContourPlot[z[x + I y] - z[-1/(x + I y)], {x, -1, 1}, {y, .001, 1},
   AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

produces this:

[image]

Seemingly Mathematica recognizes that one indeed gets zero along these circular arcs...